# How can I hide a quiver or arrows? How big is a quiver?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I am trying to figure out how hiding something like a quiver would work or if there is a way to do this at all. Would hiding a quiver use a slight of hand check as the DC to spot?

This quiver doesn't need to hold many arrows but I would it easy to access as well.

My character is a Martial Rogue with plenty of skills for things like hiding and sleight of hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Slight of Hand](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/sleightOfHand.htm) Most quivers are about 3/4 the size of the wearer's back so it can hold the arrows. Most people would say this is well more than the size of a hand crossbow. An arrow is also significantly larger than a dart. By raw, it is not possible to hide your standard, mundane quiver.

Perhaps there are some magic items that do that (such as bag of holding, which you can then hide), but not the mundane one.

Of course...you could try and "misread" the chart that says "Lift a small object from a person", since "small" in D&D is 1/2 the size of a human, a quiver would fit that description.  But then your DM's just going to "misread" that as saying you now need to make that check just to carry it, not conceal it.

If you go with [epic sleight of hand](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/skills.htm), or magic, then you could, but I think you already figured this out.

Comment: Just an add-on: if you're willing to go the magical item way, handy haversack holds less than a bag of holding but lets you take stuff as a move action, so it would be more accessible, and equally hidden.